# WP8: Is it possible to get referrer for installation of app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to track the source of install from different Ads site. In Android we can get referrer tracking from  Referrer/BroadcastReceiver. Is there something similar in Windows Phone 8 or above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like this on Windows Phone.